# python: import a helper function in a module

Tags: python-2.7

In a `top` folder I have a python file (`helpers.py`) which contains a single function:

```
def play(name, verbose=False):
        if verbose:
        print name + "with verbose on"
    else:
        print name + "verbose off"
```

And in a subfolder named `project` I have second python file (`program.py`) that imports and uses helpers.py:

```
from .. import helpers as hp

def main(device,verbose=False):
    hp.play(device)
    #here goes the code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Test the program
    main('Foo')
    main('Foo', verbose=True)
```

Both folders contain the `__init__.py` file to allow module importing. I want to execute the program.py file to test the main function.
Following [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) I try to run :

```
python -m top.project.program
```

getting

```
# /usr/bin/python: No module named top.project
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in a comment of the accepted answer in the link I posted in my question. It matters from which directory you are executing your python command from. The code works when executing the following shell command:

```
python -m top.project.program
```

From the `top` directory only. It is not working when executed from its subdirectory `project`.

Answer (score 0):

`-m` doesn't indicate an import; it is expecting the path to the module you wish to execute.  So it probably wants `-m top/project/program.py` (although you may need to provide an absolute path).

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: Tried with a full path. It gives me ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package